# How to let snippets ignore beginning "$"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code to write markdown and I set some snippets for convenience, however, snippets does not work while I write inline math since VS code thought I was writing something beginning with "$", that is

[image]

I expect it will work like

[image]

Comment: the snippet prefix uses the last word before the cursor, maybe `$` is marked as a word character in the Markdown language file

Comment: Can I change it?

Comment: what if you add `$matrix` and `$$matrix` as possible prefixes